# Group by and Join on same Table Sql - PostgreSql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
Id | Name       | ParentId | Hierarchy
1  | California | 1        | 1
2  | San Deigo  | 1        | 2
3  | Bay Area   | 1        | 2
4  | San Fran   | 1        | 2
```

Hierachy 1 indicates top level like California. Hierarchy 2 indicate second level like state/region in California e.g. San Diego. Hierarchy 3 indicates third level like street in San Diego.
Is it possible to get districts with parent codes with hierarchy 2. It looks like it needs group by and join in same table.

Comment: could you please provide your expected output?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Similar in many ways, different in others.)

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

> Is it possible to get districts with parent codes with hierarchy 2?

This is just a select:

```
select t.districtname, t.parencdoe 
from t
where t.hierarhy = 2;
```

Your data is malformed.  You should have a **parentid** column that refers to the primary key of the table.  The `parentcode` is not appropriate.  It also seems redundant to have columns like `regionname` in all rows.

Comment: Thanks @gordon for replying. Yes, its a parentId. I have updated the post

Comment: Please see my answer. If anything better, let me know thank you.

Comment: @Gauravsa . . . You should ask a *new* question.  This answered the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I have comeup with the following solution:

```
select p.name as Parent,
       c.name as Child      
FROM
    theTable p
INNER JOIN theTable c ON p.id = c.parentId
where p.hierarchy = 1
```